# PHP Insert values into two tables and insert keys from those tables into link table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, foreign-keys, insert-into

I'm new to PHP and I am interested in adding primary key ID's from two tables in a link table called sub_credits (inserting submit_id and credits_id) as foreign keys right after inserting values in those tables. Any help would be great! Here is my code:

```
                    //write the data to the database
                    $query1 = "INSERT INTO submissions (user_id, date, " . 
                             "submission_type, title, zipfile, " . 
                             "copyright, review)" . 
                             "VALUES ('" . $_SESSION['user_id']. "', NOW(), " . 
                             "'$submission_type', '$title', " . 
                             "'$zipfile', '$copyright', '$review' )";
                    $query2 = "INSERT INTO credits (credits) VALUES ('$credits')";
                    mysqli_query($dbc, $query1)
                            or die ('Data not inserted.');
                    mysqli_query($dbc, $query2)
                            or die ('Data not inserted.');
```

Comment: What's the question you're asking?

Comment: Why did you concatenate the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the ids using  **`mysql_insert_id();`**

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO submissions (user_id, date, " . 
                         "submission_type, title, zipfile, " . 
                         "copyright, review)" . 
                         "VALUES ('" . $_SESSION['user_id']. "', NOW(), " . 
                         "'$submission_type', '$title', " . 
                         "'$zipfile', '$copyright', '$review' )";
mysqli_query($dbc, $query1) or die ('Data not inserted.');
$id1 = mysql_insert_id();

$query2 = "INSERT INTO credits (credits) VALUES ('$credits')";

mysqli_query($dbc, $query2) or die ('Data not inserted.');
$id2 = mysql_insert_id();
```

you can use `$id1` & `$id2` to insert to new table using new insert query.

```
$query3 = "INSERT INTO new_table(submissions_id,credits_id) VALUES ('$id1','$id2')";
mysqli_query($dbc, $query3) or die ('Data not inserted.');
```

where `submissions_id,credits_id` are **foreign keys** of new table

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! :)